# Issue with Touchpal Contacts

Tags: contacts, phone-app

I just downloaded the [Touchpal Contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cootek.smartdialer&hl=en) app to my Galaxy Nexus (ICS). Under `Settings->Contacts and Lists`, I have 'Contacts without phone' unchecked, and, indeed, the contacts displayed are only those with phone numbers associated with them. Yet,  when I use the provided search bar to find contacts, it brings up all contacts even those without phone numbers. Any advice?

If it's relevant, my contacts are coming from Google Contacts.

Comment: That would seem to be by design, no? You're only **displaying** contacts with phone numbers. It doesn't necessarily follow that those are the only contacts being **synced**.